# move_uploaded_file выдает “failed to open stream: Permission denied ”

Tags: php, apache, centos7, selinux

Понимаю, что тема ***затертая до дыр***, но все-таки. Есть форма, которая методом POST отправляется файл .jpeg. Нужно его сохранить в директорию /var/www/html/foto/. Есть **скрипт**, который обрабатывает и **сохраняет файл**:

```
 if (isset($_FILES['foto'])) {
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/foto/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);
    //Перемещаем файл из временной папки в указанную
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
      echo "Файл загружен";
    }
```

На директорию /foto/, как, в принципе, и на директориях - /html/,/www/,/var/ стоят права доступа 777, также права доступа 777 стоят и на скрипте /var/www/html/index.php.Ошибка:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/foto/doroga.jpeg): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/logger.php on line 32
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpNuynNq' to
>   '/var/www/html/foto/doroga.jpeg' in /var/www/html/logger.php on line
>   32

В 32 строке:
`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))`.
Понимаю, что проблема связана всеравно с правами доступа, так как скрипт рабочий, на другом сервере отлично все записывается, но не знаю как решить проблему! Хелп. 
Апач запущен от root:

```
 ps auxwwww | grep httpd
root     26302  0.0  0.2 419648 16656 ?        Ss   12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   26303  0.0  0.1 421928 11464 ?        S    12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   26304  0.0  0.1 421732  9528 ?        S    12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   26305  0.0  0.1 421732  9528 ?        S    12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   26306  0.0  0.1 421732  9528 ?        S    12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   26307  0.0  0.1 421732  9528 ?        S    12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   26308  0.0  0.1 421732  9528 ?        S    12:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root     26430  0.0  0.0 112728   972 pts/0    S+   12:44   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

Стоит Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.1.19.

Comment: что говорит команда `sestatus`?

Comment: @de_frag                                                                                                                                           
 > `[root@localhost etc]# sestatus
> SELinux status:                 enabled
> SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
> SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
> Loaded policy name:             targeted
> Current mode:                   enforcing
> Mode from config file:          enforcing
> Policy MLS status:              enabled`
`Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed`
'Max kernel policy version:      31'

Comment: пробуйте так `chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t  /var/www/html/foto/ -R`

Comment: @de_frag Cпасибо огромное! `chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/foto/ -R` - помогло!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

При включенном в системе `selinux` каталог для аплоада файлов требует дополнительных разрешений. Для их добавления нужна следующая команда:

```
chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/foto/ -R
```